# convert jquery greybox into favelet

Tags: jquery, bookmarklet

Hi anyone can help me with converting this into a bookmarklet 
to load an external site in a iframe inside an overlay like how it is done on 
http://jquery.com/demo/grey/

thnx

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: javascript:var s=document.createElement(’script’);s.setAttribute(’src’,′http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js’);document.body.appendChild(s);
var p=document.createElement(’script’);p.setAttribute(’src’,′http://xyz.com/greybox.js’);document.body.appendChild(p);
var c=document.createElement(’link’);c.setAttribute(’href’,′http://xyz.com/greybox.css’);document.body.appendChild(c);
$(document).ready(function(){GB_show("Bookmarklet","http://www.gmail.com/",470,600);return
false;});

this is what i have so far

Answer (score 0):

I would put all your actual code in an external file that you just load. See http://paulisageek.com/nodeSelector/.

The bookmarklet code is :

```
javascript:(
   function() { 
      var s=document.createElement("script");
          s.charset="UTF-8";
          s.src="http://paulisageek.com/nodeSelector/ns.js";
      document.body.appendChild(s)
   })();
```

which then in tern loads jquery and does some fancy stuff. It also makes updating it much easier (since you don't have to get your users to change the bookmarklet).

Comment: thnx paul am going about the same way now :)